# Sequelize: how to find a Max element

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am issue while forming a sequelize query :

My Native query is something.

```
       SELECT max(id),vehicleID FROM `vehicles` WHERE `vehicles`.`vsr_id`=342;
```

For this i am trying to build Code which something like this.

```
    Vehicle.find({ where: { 'vsr_id': 342 }, order : [sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('id'))] }).success(function(vehicles){
       console.log("Something i got" + vehicles)
        })
```

It throwing an error : sequelize Object [object Object] has no method 'col'
and i refered from this URL:
           http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/models#block-34-line-8

Any code missings from my end. Please help me out

FYI: Ignore semicolons

Comment: Vehicle.find({ where: { 'vsr_id': vsr_vehicle.vsr_id }, attributes: ['id', 'vehicleID'],'order': 'id DESC' }).success(function(vehicles){
      console.log("Something i got" + vehicles)
           
    })

Answer (score 26):

Can you please try,

```
Vehicle.max('id', {where : {'vsr_id': 342 }})
.then(function(vehicle_id){
   ...
})
.error(function(error){
   ...
});
```

Comment: the function dos not return the `vehicle`, instead it returns the `id` of that vehicle

Answer (score 5):

That query should be possible with:

```
Vehicle.findAll({
  attributes: [
     sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('id'))
  ],
  where: {
    { 'vsr_id': 342 }
  }
});
```

Comment: You should update the attributes to add an alias `[sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('id')), "id"]`

Answer (score 4):

try to use:

```
Vehicle.findAll({
        attributes: [Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('id'))],
        raw: true,
    })
```

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318718/sequelize-orm-get-max-id-by-grouping) for more information.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use sequelize.col to refer to the column and sequelize won't add "'", which is causing the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Vehicle.findAll({
    where: {},
    ....
    attributes:[[sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('id')),'max']]
})
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.