# Sequelize ORM get max id by grouping

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize ORM for DB operation in my nodejs project. Here I wrote a simple sequelize query to retrieve max ids of each driver in a driverlocation model.

```
 global.driverlocationhistory.findAll({
        attributes: [global._sequelize.fn("max", global._sequelize.col('id'))],
        group: ["driverId"]
 }).then(function (results) {
        objDrvr = results;
 })
```

This is not returning any value as well as not giving any kind of error. But the database has values. When executing above sequelize query, it is created SQL query. (It can be seen in console window after running the server using node server.js) Here is the executing query.

```
SELECT max(`id`) FROM `driverlocationhistory` AS `driverlocationhistory` GROUP BY `driverId`;
```

SQL-query above is executed in mysql server and there are results for the query.

Why is it not retrieving data for sequelize query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try,

```
await DIR.ProfileModel.findAll({
    attributes: [
        [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('profile_id')), 'profile_id'],
    ],
    group: ['user_id'],
    raw: true,
});
```

Sequelize generate:

> Executing (default): SELECT MAX(`profile_id`) FROM `profile` AS
>   `profile` GROUP BY `user_id`;

And return results:

```
{ profile_id: 106 },
{ profile_id: 187 },
{ profile_id: 109 },
{ profile_id: 111 },
{ profile_id: 112 },
{ profile_id: 113 },
{ profile_id: 115 },
{ profile_id: 116 },
{ profile_id: 117 },
{ profile_id: 120 },
{ profile_id: 121 },
```

If raw is false, dataValues is empty, I have no idea why

```
{
    profile {
        dataValues: {},
        _previousDataValues: {},
        _changed: {},
        _modelOptions:
        {
            timestamps: false,
            validate: {},
            freezeTableName: false,
            underscored: false,
            underscoredAll: false,
            paranoid: false,
            rejectOnEmpty: false,
            whereCollection: null,
            schema: null,
            schemaDelimiter: '',
            defaultScope: {},
            scopes: [],
            indexes: [],
            name: [Object],
            omitNull: false,
            charset: 'utf8',
            collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
            tableName: 'profile',
            sequelize: [Object],
            hooks: [Object],
            uniqueKeys: {}
        },
    }
}
```

> Sometimes you might be expecting a massive dataset that you just want
>   to display, without manipulation. For each row you select, Sequelize
>   creates an instance with functions for update, delete, get
>   associations etc. If you have thousands of rows, this might take some
>   time. If you only need the raw data and don't want to update anything,
>   you can do like this to get the raw data.

[Read docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#raw-queries)

Good luck!

Comment: Can then sweep the answer as correct? For the next person to know about this

Comment: Done... Thanks :)